# Problem connecting between Macs in the same network

Tags: macos, network

I have three Macs (MBP, MBA1 and MBA2) in the same network, connected over WiFi. I need to `ssh` from the MBP to the other two Macs, but sometimes this stops working. When it does, I can't in any way reach the MBP from the MBAs and vice-versa -- not even through `ping`. `arp` shows the correct IP and MAC addresses on both machines, but they simply can't reach other. However, each Mac can access the internet, as well as other machines on the network -- they simply have a problem connecting to each other. This just happened, and after restarting the MBA, I was able to connect again, but it's not really practical to reboot a computer multiple times per day.

I really have no idea where to start trying to fix this problem. Any suggestions?

Extra details: I have two access points, a D-Link DIR-882 on the upper floor and a Time Capsule (latest model before discontinuing, software version 4.9.1) on the lower floor. I have a Gigabit Ethernet cable running from the D-Link to the Time Capsule, connected on the WAN port of the Time Capsule, and with the Time Capsule configured in bridge mode, with the DHCP server off. Both use the same SSIDs for WiFi. Firewall is off on all Macs.

Additionally, while the problem mentioned above is intermittent, I do have a similar issue that is quite consistent: with the MBAs in the upper floor, when I walk to the lower floor with my MBP and it switches over to the Time Capsule for WiFi (since it's the physically closest router), then I simply can't connect to the MBA -- but I can still connect to the internet and every other machine in my network. The only time I recall this issue going away was immediately after a reboot of the Time Capsule, but otherwise, it happens every single time.

Comment: Have you tried a traceroute between the machines?

Comment: @swineone I think I'm suspecting the same thing as you: The symptoms seem to occur when crossing router domains. So it is more likely that the root cause is either in your D-Link or in your Time Capsule, rather than in your Macs. Just an educated hunch that will need significantly more debugging to prove out. I would start by trying to force all your Macs to use either the D-Link or the TC (perhaps by disconnecting the other one) and see if the problem persists. I don't know what specific settings your routers expose but you can also play with bridging and wireless radio options.

Comment: @MongoTheGeek `traceroute` fails from the very first hop. `ping` just times out every time.

Comment: @pion I would be inclined to agree, except that this only happens between the Macs. I have all sorts of devices in my network: Linux machines, a Windows PC, Apple TVs, some special-purpose devices, etc. Let's call M the set of Macs and O the set of other devices (not Macs) in my network. There is no issue connecting between anyone in O and anyone else in O; or between anyone in M and anyone in O and vice-versa; only between two machines in M, each in a different floor.

Comment: @pion it's unfeasible to disconnect the D-Link (it's routing the internet to everyone else), and impractical to disconnect the TC since it extends the reach of my network to places the D-Link wouldn't reach (and also does double duty as an Ethernet switch). I also don't see how that would help -- if everyone is connected to the D-Link, there are no connection issues at all. Disconnecting the TC would restrict me to this working state, so everything should just work fine. What I will try to do is source a different router to use in place of the TC temporarily to see if it makes a difference.